# Set download path for fireFTP

Tags: firefox, fireftp

I use fireFTP as a simple FTP client, mostly for just touching things up on the server, and occasionally downloading some files back to my machine.

The downloads always go straight to the root of the drive, but ideally I'd like them to drop straight to my Desktop or Downloads folder. Any idea how I can set this up?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error i found the answer, when you open Fireftp and login to your server you will have 4 panels - from left to right

- Local machine tree
- Local machine detail section
- Server tree
- Server detail section

If you want to download something to say the downloads folder on your local machine have the downloads folder selected in the **Local machine tree** then right click the file you want in the **Server detail section** and select download, this will then download that file to your downloads section.